# Should app config files be in jboss/bin directory?

Tags: web-applications, jboss, classpath

I am a Integration Engineer for a software company.  My development team has generated various jboss .ear applications that rely on configuration files being in the jboss/bin directory   and setting the CLASSPATH externally using batch files (on Windows from an external LIB directory) rather than using jboss's internally loaded classes.   Is this the right/standard way of doing things?  Would some other location be better (for the config files)  such as jboss/server/instancename/deploy   or some other directory?   Any opinons on how I can direct my development team to doing things in a best practices fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend `/path/to/jboss/server/$DEPLOYDIRECTORY/conf`.  It's called `conf` for a reason.

Comment: is $DEPLOYDIRECTORY an actual environment variable for JBoss?   is there an environment variable for "/path/to/jboss" ?

Comment: No.  The deploy directory is specified with the flag `-c`.  The default deploy directory is named `default` unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: thanks. your the only one who answered. i appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck.